# Javascript show/hide div based on multiple dropdown selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 dropdown selections. What I want to achieve is when `type-select == mcd` and `duration-select == 24` and `sc-select == True` I want to show div called `COMBINATION_1`, and hide all other .divs. 
And I wanna do this for all possible combinations.
I know how to do it when one dropdown is selected but got no idea how to make it work with multiple selections.

This is my filters HTML:

```
<div id="option-filters">
<p class="l">Options:</p>
<ul class="filters">
    <li>
        <label for="type-select">Type</label>
        <select id="type-select" class="input-select">
            <option id="type-mcd" value="mcd"> GA</option>
            <option id="type-cp" value="cp"> CP</option>
            <option id="type-prp2pop" value="prp2pop"> PRP2POP</option>
            <option id="type-mnp" value="mnp"> MNP</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="duration-select">Duration</label>
        <select id="duration-select" class="input-select">
            <option id="duration-24" value="24"> 24 </option>
            <option id="duration-12" value="12"> 12 </option>
            <option id="duration-0" value="0"> 0 </option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="sc-select"> Device </label>
        <select id="sc-select" class="input-select">
            <option id="sc-true" value="True"> SC</option>
            <option id="sc-false" value="False"> NO SC </option>
            <option id="sc-simonly" value="SimOnly"> NONE </option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you need to call onchange event on all three dropdown and check the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way, thought a bit too much of code :). This works when the page loads and on change too.

```js
var $selects = $('.filters select');
$selects.on('change', getValues).first().trigger("change");
function getValues() {
    var vals = $selects.map(function() {
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    if (vals.join('') === "mcd24True") {
        alert ("I am in");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="option-filters">
<p class="l">Options:</p>
<ul class="filters">
    <li>
        <label for="type-select">Type</label>
        <select id="type-select" class="input-select">
            <option id="type-mcd" value="mcd"> GA</option>
            <option id="type-cp" value="cp"> CP</option>
            <option id="type-prp2pop" value="prp2pop"> PRP2POP</option>
            <option id="type-mnp" value="mnp"> MNP</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="duration-select">Duration</label>
        <select id="duration-select" class="input-select">
            <option id="duration-24" value="24"> 24 </option>
            <option id="duration-12" value="12"> 12 </option>
            <option id="duration-0" value="0"> 0 </option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="sc-select"> Device </label>
        <select id="sc-select" class="input-select">
            <option id="sc-true" value="True"> SC</option>
            <option id="sc-false" value="False"> NO SC </option>
            <option id="sc-simonly" value="SimOnly"> NONE </option>
        </select>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works great too, and it's shorter code since I'll have like 12 different combinations to show/hide. And it's great since it works on page load. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#type-select, #duration-select, #sc-select').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#type-select').val() == 'mcd' && $('#duration-select').val() == 24 && $('#sc-select').val() == 'True') {
        // your code 
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried the following(btw changed id names for HTML in meantime), but it's not giving me any results :/

`<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#contract-type-select, #contract-duration-select, #contract-sc-select').on('change', function() {
  if ($('#contract-type-select').val() == 'mcd' && $('#contract-duration-select').val() == 24 && $('#contract-sc-select').val == 'True') {
   $('.tarif-price').hide();
  }
 });
});
</script>`

Comment: You are missing `()` in last condition replace `$('#contract-sc-select').val == 'True'` with `$('#contract-sc-select').val() == 'True'`

Comment: Didn't even notice this stupid mistake. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: One more thing, mcd & 24 & true is my default state, but this says that on change it will be hidden. How can I set it to be hidden when page is loaded?
I check here https://api.jquery.com/category/events/form-events/ but none of those events help my situation.